# How to create regex for optional float value in UITextField?

Tags: ios, regex, swift3, uitextfield, nsregularexpression

Im trying to get weight from the user in a UITextField. Where the value can be some thing like this

9

9.56

50

50.75

Currently I've tried this and not working.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let Regex = "([0-9]){0,2}\\.([0-9]){0,2}"
        let TestResult = NSPredicate.init(format:"SELF MATCHES %@",Regex)
        return TestResult.evaluate(with: textField.text! + string)
    }
```

It always returns false.

123456.123456 should be false

12.12 should be true

Comment: Are you trying to extract all these values? Or are you validating them as separate strings? Your current code just checks if a string matches your pattern fully (`MATCHES` requires a full string match).

Comment: Try `"[0-9]{0,2}(?:[.][0-9]{1,2})?"` just in case. This will also match an empty string though.

Comment: @nirav D I've tried it and not working.

Comment: @arunsiva It is perfect and working solution of what your need

Comment: @NiravD The given link assumes I have a string. But I'm tying to validate when char by char is being typed. I'm not able to type "." after entering 2 chars.

Comment: @NiravD Thanks. I thought you could answer the question.

Comment: @arunsiva I haven't checked it but as you told you don't able to add `.` then I understand reopen the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this if you want to match only these formats:

```
.1  
.12  
1  
1.  
1.1  
1.12  
12  
12.  
12.1  
12.12
```

`^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})$`

Will not match an empty string.

Explained

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?:                           # --------------
      \d{1,2}                       # one or two digits
      (?: \. \d{0,2} )?             # optional '.' and 0 to 2 digits
   |                              # or,
      \. \d{1,2}                    # '.' and 1 or 2 digits
 )                             # --------------
 $                             # EOS
```

Note - *Always use anchors as it makes this a self contained portable solution!!*
Also, for reference this `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)` is the core standard for language parsing of a number (sans decoration).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one : `^\d{1,2}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DXtk9H/4)

**Explanation**

`^` From start of line,

`\d{1,2}` match any number of digits between 1 on 2 times

`(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?` with optional 1 or 2 decimals (`?:` is a non capturing group)

`$` until end of line

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I want to restrict to 2 chars before "." and 2 chars after "."

Comment: You do not need any anchors. The pattern is anchored by default.

Comment: Answer modified to fit your needs

Comment: I would recommend to use `[.,]` for decimal separator or take the current decimal separator from `Locale`.

Comment: @Sulthan good point. @Wiktor if I don't use start and end of line anchors can I ensure it won't match `50a` or `9.1a` ?

Comment: @stej4n: If you do not know how to use regex in iOS, why post answers that might be incompatible with this regex flavor/code? See `NSPredicate.init(format:"SELF MATCHES %@",Regex)`.

Comment: Didn't know it was anchored by default. I would sleep less stupid tonight

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

[0-9]{2,2}?([.][0-9]{2,2}?)?